# Один сортированный список из двух таблиц

Tags: sql, mysql

Есть несколько таблиц с описаниями разных сущностей у которых также есть сходные аттрибуты(id, title, created-at). id, естественно, дублируются. Как при помощи SQL-запроса вывести единый список этих объектов, отсортированных по времени создания «created-at»?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select id, title, "created-at" from t1
union all
select id, title, "created-at" from t2
order by "created-at"
```